# Building a Matlab table from a nested Matlab struct

Tags: matlab

How would I build a table from the Matlab structure that the below code produces?

```
%create a nested structure
a_1=struct('a',50,'b',60);
a_2=struct('a',45','c',90);
a_3=struct('c',105,'d',32);
a=struct('Model1',a_1,'Model2',a_2,'Model3',a_3);
```

The desired output would look like the output from the below code:

```
%desired output 
a=[50;45;0];
b=[60;0;0];
c=[0;90;105];
d=[0;0;30];
row_names={'Model1','Model2','Model3'};
col_names={'a','b','c','d'};

T=table(a,b,c,d,'RowNames',row_names)
```

Please note however that I had to fill the blanks with `0`s to write this code but it would be better to have something else there, such as `'-'` or `N/A`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really nice, but something like this can do it for you. Obtaining the row names is quite easy using `fieldnames`.

```
row_names = fieldnames(a);
```

In order to ensure the correct length of all results, it is useful to obtain all possible columns for the table.

```
% Obtain all existing fields to correctly assign all zeros
all_fields = {};

for r = 1:length(row_names)    
    act = eval('a.(row_names{r})');

    fields = fieldnames(act);

    all_fields = union(all_fields,fields);
end
```

And then set it to zero with the correct size. This avoids wring dimensions when used inside of the table.

```
% Set everything to zero
for f_num = 1:length(all_fields)
    res.(all_fields{f_num}) = zeros(size(row_names));
end
```

Finally, one must go through all initial structures and add the values to the corresponding results.

```
% Overwrite zeros by existing values
for r = 1:length(row_names)    
    act = eval('a.(row_names{r})');

    fields = fieldnames(act);

    for f = 1:length(fields)
        res.(fields{f})(r) = act.(fields{f});
    end
end

table(res.a,res.b,res.c,res.d,'RowNames',row_names)
```

I have used a `struct` for the results in order to avoid more evals.